# relation according to height factor between two specific trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees, data-structure

I have $2$ trees as follows:

$First$
[image]

$Second$
[image]

I want to find a relation between these **two trees**, I need this relation: if we get height of the second three as $H$ what is the **relation** between $height$ of these two example according to $H$?

Comment: It isn’t at all clear how you’re labelling the leaves, since the first picture suggests that there should be $2^n$ leaves if the height is $n$, not $n+1$ as you seem to have shown. If I ignore the labels and just look at the pictures, it appears that the trees have the same height, namely, the length of the leftmost branch.

Comment: I suspect that there is information in the example that isn’t present in the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the second tree is $n$, the length of the path from the vertex $2^0$ to the root. Problem $5$ in [the PDF](http://dml.ir/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/SPR-S12-F-Sol.pdf) specifies that $n+1=2^N$, so $\log_2(n+1)=N$, and the claim is that the height of the first tree is $N$. To see this, let $h$ be the height of this tree; it has $2^N$ leaves, and they are on level $h$. Clearly level $h-1$ has half as many nodes as level $h$, so it has $2^{N-1}$ nodes. Similarly, level $h-2$ has $2^{N-2}$ nodes, and in general level $h-i$ has $2^{N-i}$ nodes for $i=0,\ldots,N$. Thus, level $h-N$ has $2^{N-N}=1$ node; clearly that node is the root of the tree, so it is on level $0$, i.e., $h-N=0$. But then $h=N$, as claimed.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph: Yes, that’s right.